# What is the meaning of "Cut-in Current" and "LRA"

Tags: current, cut-in

I was reading the specification of my refrigerator's Compressor where i found the following table:

[image]

Could you please tell me in non technical terms what is "**Cut-in Current**" and "**LRA**"

Answer (score 1):

LRA usually means "locked rotor amperes." This the current that the motor draws when the rotor is mechanically "locked" or prevented from turning. In the table "rated after 4 sec. UL984) suggests that UL standard 984 may contain something that alters the usual definition.

"Cut-in" and "cut-out" appear to be terms used in the refrigeration industry to refer to starting and stopping the compressor as it cycles on and off in response to the thermostat. "Cut-in" would then refer to the current drawn by the compressor when it starts.

Using the customary motor industry definition of LRA, LRA is the highest current that the motor could ever draw. Upon starting, the rotor is at a standstill, but it is not prevented from turning, so LRA is drawn only for a fraction of a second before the rotor begins to turn. After that, the current drops to a lower level as the motor accelerates. That raises a question with the definition of "LRA" and "cut-in" proposed above. The table indicates that LRA is equal to cut-in current for an "HST" (high starting-torque) motor, but LRA is less than cut-in current for a "LST" (low starting-torque) motor. That is inconsistent with the usual assumption that LRA is seen only in the instant after starting before the rotor begins to turn.

Unfortunately, UL standards are not available online to read without purchase. Perhaps a detailed explanation of UL 984 can be found. Perhaps a better explanation can be found at a refrigeration Q and A or discussion site.